# Xamarin Forms - Prism - OnNavigatedTo Calling Twice

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, prism

So, I've been developing an App for 2 months with prism, and just now I've realized that the method OnNavigatedTo is been calling twice when I select an Item from a MasterDetailPage.

I have no clue why it is happening, I'm sure I'm missing something but I'm about two days trying to solve it.

I'll put some code here, and if u guys need more info I can post more detailed.

Observation: When I'm in the page "A" and I choose the page "A" in the master detail item list, the OnNavigatedTo is called only once, but when I'm in Page "B" and I choose the page "A", The OnNavigatedTo is called twice.

Since now, Thank you guys and sorry about the ignorance.

MasterDetailPage MVVM:

```
public class PrincipalMasterDetailPageViewModel : ViewModelBase {
        public ObservableCollection<PrincipalMasterPageItem> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public PrincipalMasterDetailPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<PrincipalMasterPageItem>();
        }
        public async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters) {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
            .. Here I'm calling an API, thats why I have the async
        }
    }
```

Custom Navigation Page MVVM:

```
public class PrincipalNavigationPageViewModel : ViewModelBase {
        public PrincipalNavigationPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService) {
        }
    }
```

The Page that I actually show when I select an item in masterdetailpage item list:

```
public class NewPageTestViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public NewPageTestViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {

        }

        public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
            Debug.WriteLine("Calling twice HERE!");
        }
    }
```

The RegisterTypes of these three examples:

```
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<PrincipalMasterDetailPage>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<PrincipalNavigationPage>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NewPageTest>();
```

How do I call other pages from PrincipalMasterDetailPageViewModel:

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync(string.Format("PrincipalNavigationPage/{0}", item.TargetPageName));
```

In App.cs I start like the following because I need the login page first:

```
protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage");
        }
```

When the user log in, It navigate like this:

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/PrincipalMasterDetailPage/PrincipalNavigationPage/WhateverPageIWantTo");
```

Comment: How do you register the views at the container and how do you call the `NavigateTo`? Can you provide some code there?

Comment: @Mardukar Sure, I've edited the post with the information u wanted.

Comment: Not working yet... =[

Comment: No,
Navigate from A to B: called twice (no matter how many times I navigate)
Navigate from A to A: called once

Comment: @Mardukar I have updated to show How the app start and how I navigate for the first time to the PrincipalMasterDetailPage in case it is important

Comment: @Mardukar One thing that I saw now, it is that when I Log in, the principal master detail page->OnNavigatedTo is called twice too, so my list items is duplicated =[

Comment: I think when you navigate the `NavigationService` finds two pages for the given name and calls them both. This would explain why it only happens when you navigate to "A".

Comment: Hmmmm, What would I do to check this? maybe see if all the places I call a new page have the same NavigationPage name?

Comment: Can you set a name at `RegisterForNavigation`? Similar to this `container.RegisterInstance("B1", container.Resolve<NewPageTest>())`. This code was written with Prism 4. So the method names can be a bit different in newer versions.

Comment: I tried now that u said, and didn't work =[,

Its called like this: containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<PrincipalNavigationPage>("nameHere");

Comment: I did notice something now while I'm testing, whenever I select an item, the PrincipalNavigationPage "OnNavigatedTo" is called once, and its constructor too, the constructor of the page that PrincipalNavigationPage is keeping is called once too, just the OnNavigatedTo is being called twice D=

Comment: Did you find any solution?I am having the same problem

Comment: @GeorgePapadakis Not solved yet =[, if you find any solution, please share D=

Comment: @MarcioE.H https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1460#issuecomment-394003489

Comment: @GeorgePapadakis, Thank you, that's a huge feedback, I've tried updating XF to the last version and still didn't work, I'll wait for the 7.1 prism version and see what happens, thank you again!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if anybody is still interested in this but I ran into the same issue and figured out what is going on.

All code samples I found register a NavigationPage like this:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>("Navigation");
```

In order to be able to do something like this on app launch:

```
 NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"Main/Navigation/Home");
```

However, the problem seems to be that when this NavigationPage is instantiated without a specific ViewModel assinged to it, the 'INavigationAware' events are somehow propagated to the MasterDetailPage's ViewModel resulting in the events on that one to be called twice.

I fixed it by registering the NavigationPage for Navigation with a ViewModel like this:

```
    containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage, NavigationPageViewModel>("Navigation");
```

The ViewModel itself is nothing special:

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Unity.Attributes;

namespace SocialRecipe.ViewModels
{
    public class NavigationPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public NavigationPageViewModel()
        {

        }

        public override void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
        }

        public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
        }

        public override void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This way the events of the NavigationPage are routed to the NavigationPageViewModel and are no longer propagated to the MasterDetailPage…

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and explanation Peter, I think it'll do the job, I'll test it when possible and share if it worked for me!

Comment: It worked!, after adding the ViewModel in the second Type, it doesn't duplicate anymore

Comment: I've been mildly irritated by this issue for several weeks of development but not enough to really dig into it before today.  Its not an obvious fix so I'm sure you saved me hours of research.  Thanks!

Comment: Welp, wrong issue for me, turns out it was the fact that I subscribed to an event with EventAggregator in a VM constructor and the constructor was getting called twice and subscribing twice to the same event. Different issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed some inconsistent results with Prism as well from a previous project. If you are only seeing it now and it worked previously I would try and backtrack to see if the version you used was different.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues

Comment: I'll try the backtrack, thank you!
I realized that it is being called twice just now that the project is about 70%, it is my fault, but I hope its not a prism problem, because it is a good tool and I'll be sad if I need to remove prism from project.