# Prism navigate to same page twice

Tags: xamarin, prism

In XamarinForms, I have a page in a navigationPage and I want to navigate to another instance of the same page. Is is possible?
I´m using `navigationService.NavigateAsync($"NavigationPage/{pageKey}", parameters);` but it is not doing any navigation, it stay in the same page.

Comment: Is `NavigatedTo` called for your second navigation?

Comment: google `xamarin prism have two instances of same page` shows several similar questions, including https://stackoverflow.com/q/7906156/199364 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716729/navigation-issue-in-xamarin-forms-with-same-page-type-multiple-time.

Comment: `NavigateTo` is not called in the second navigation

Comment: see this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254146/xamarin-forms-prism-onnavigatedto-calling-twice